# Wicket FeedbackPanel has empty message when used with AjaxFallBackButton

Tags: ajax, wicket, feedbackpanel

I am using BeanValidation for Form inputs with AjaxFallbackButton to submit the Form. And FeedbackPanel for showing errors. When I give invalid input the form does not submit but feedbackpanel is not showing.

onError, form.getFeedbackMessages() returns empty array.

Wicket version 6.18.0.

Here is the code:

```
    Form<Address> form = getForm();
    add(form);

    FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackMessage");
    feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(feedbackPanel);     


public Form<Address> getForm() {

    CompoundPropertyModel<Address> model = new CompoundPropertyModel<Address>(address);
    final Form<Address> form = new Form<Address>("addressForm", model);

    form.add(new Label("fNameLabel", new ResourceModel("fNameLabel")));
    form.add(new Label("lNameLabel", new ResourceModel("lNameLabel")));
    form.add(new Label("workLabel", new ResourceModel("workLabel")));
    form.add(new Label("homeLabel", new ResourceModel("homeLabel")));

    form.add(new TextField<String>("firstName").add(new PropertyValidator<String>()));
    form.add(new TextField<String>("lastName").add(new PropertyValidator<String>()));
    form.add(new TextField<String>("homeLocation").add(new PropertyValidator<String>()));
    form.add(new TextField<String>("workLocation").add(new PropertyValidator<String>()));
    form.add(new AjaxFallbackButton("submit", form) {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6672729206839722437L;

        @Override
        protected void onError(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form form) {   
            Page page = target.getPage();
            for (Component component : page.visitChildren()) {
                String markupId = component.getMarkupId();
                if (markupId.contains("feedbackMessage")) {
                    if (form.hasFeedbackMessage()) {

                        System.out.println(form.getFeedbackMessages());
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {

            if (address.getFirstName() != null) {
                AddressGenerator.getInstance().add(address);
                modalWindow.closeCurrent(target);
            }
        }
    });

    return form;
}
```

Form is in ModalWindow.

Answer (score 0):

`Component#getFeedbackMessages()` returns the messages **only** for this component instance. It doesn't visit the children!

Update your `onError()` method with:

```
    @Override
    protected void onError(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form form) {   
        target.add(feedbackPanel);
    }
```

You can use `if (form.hasError())` but since you are in `AjaxFallbackButton#onError()` it means there is an error.

Comment: See for collecting feedback messages  the `FeedbackMessagesModel`, that is what is used in the `FeedbackPanel`

Comment: Updated my answer.